# Problem while reading the File in a eclipse Plugin application

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I 've developed an eclipse plugin and in that I have a java file trying to read directories and then populate result accordingly.
When I try to run the file from eclipse itself through Run>Java application , it gives me proper result but as soon as I try to run the same through Eclipse Application, it is throwing NullPointerException because unable to find the directory.

I tried the following ways-
Suppose , I have a package as -

**Package - com.test.abhishek.file.java.TestWork.java**

**Directories - com.test.abhishek.file.java.Dir1
                   com.test.abhishek.file.java.Dir2**
Now in TestWork.java-
**InputStream is =  HelpContentView.class.getResourceAsStream("/"+dirName);****

The above line is getting failed.
How should I keep my directory and where so that it will run as an eclipse plug-in as well.

Tried to find the class path by 
**TestWork.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath()** and getting the output as **/**
So now where should I dump my directories to ressolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need the findEntries API.

For some example code, check out the related question (and answer) at [How to test if a URL from an Eclipse bundle is a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582375/how-to-test-if-a-url-from-an-eclipse-bundle-is-a-directory)

Comment: Paul .... Can you please explain me the scenario in eclipse. I mean how to debug it.

Comment: Find the build.properties file in the package manager.  Open it. Make sure that your needed resources are checked.

Comment: @Abhishek Updated my answer after reading your additional explanation

Comment: And before I wrote the referenced code, I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716537/finding-files-and-folders-in-an-osgi-bundle

Answer (score 2):

Just trying to understand what you are doing. You have a directory within your source structure that you want to get? Eclipse plugins are normally placed in the /plugins directory jar'ed up. This means you either A) need to bundle your resources with your plugin using build.properties, or put them somewhere else in the file structure and access it using normal File IO mechanisms.

If you are creating a plugin you most likely want to use Bundle.getEntry instead

```
 public void start(BundleContext context) {
   Bundle bundle = context.getBundle();
   InputStream in = bundle.getEntry("/"+dirName").openStream();
 }
```