# How to test if a URL from an Eclipse bundle is a directory?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to populate a directory from the contents of a bundle built into my plug-in.  The following code works when the bundle is a file-system, but fails when the bundle is a JAR.

What is the best way to test if a URL is a directory?  Or is there a completely different, better approach for creating a file structure from a resource bundle?

```
    static private void bundleCopy(String dir, String destination) throws IOException {
    Bundle bundle = com.mds.apg.Activator.getDefault().getBundle();

    for (@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Enumeration<URL> en = (Enumeration<URL>) bundle.findEntries(dir, "*", true); 
            en.hasMoreElements();) {
        URL url = en.nextElement();
        String toFileName = destination + url.getPath().substring(dir.length());
        File toFile = new File(toFileName);
        InputStream in;

        try {
            in = url.openStream();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // this exception get thrown for file system directories but not for jar file ones
            if (!toFile.mkdir()) {
                throw new IOException("bundleCopy: " + "directory Creation Failed: "
                        + toFileName);
            }
            continue;
        }
        FileCopy.coreStreamCopy(in, toFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer:

The key point is that the Enumeration entries for directories end in a '/'.

The following correctly distinguishes between directories and files for both JARs and file systems:

```
    static private void bundleCopy(String dir, String destination) 
    throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    Bundle bundle = com.mds.apg.Activator.getDefault().getBundle();
    Enumeration<URL> en = bundle.findEntries(dir, "*", true);
    while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
        URL url = en.nextElement();
        String pathFromBase = url.getPath().substring(dir.length()+1);
        String toFileName = destination + pathFromBase;
        File toFile = new File(toFileName);

        if (pathFromBase.lastIndexOf('/') == pathFromBase.length() - 1) {
            // This is a directory - create it and recurse
            if (!toFile.mkdir()) {
                throw new IOException("bundleCopy: " + "directory Creation Failed: " + toFileName);
            }
        } else {
            // This is a file - copy it
            FileCopy.coreStreamCopy(url.openStream(), toFile);
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like `new File(FileLocator.resolve(url).toUri())` to convert from the Eclipse-specific URL to one using a native Java protocol.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, but when the bundle is a jar, a popup Error is generated from the toURI() call : URI is not hierarchical.  It also doesn't completely work if the bundle is a file system, since an exception is generated for files with spaces in them.